# Creating aa array table tha Ordering items from a shop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I am trying to create a java program of 4 classes for a menu shop. Basically, the options will be added to the menu and then the menu should be provided for the user in the form of 3 columns and then the user should select a certain ID for the item they want to order. This would continue until the user selceted 3 items and then the final order should be displayed on the screen in form of a table showing only the orderd items with the total price.
My question is how do I make a final array list that contains only the ordered items? Another question is how do I create the array list in the main class so that it can contain values that are in other classes? I have created objects of the other class method in the main method of the main class and I want to take the values defined in the object and put them in the array list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make an attempt first then add your code here so that others can help with the issues. Please ask only one question at a time.